# How to theme a Drupal 6 table to output array in rows and columns?

Tags: arrays, drupal-6, drupal-themes

Iam using table themes.The below seen is my entire code for my ataempt at creating a table to show values in rows and columns. The code contains registration of my theme as well. The values come from 6 arrays seen inside the code namely fileId ,fileName etc. Now using this code i am getting this output http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1166-290.html.
    The output i desire must look like this http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1166-289.html. The array is being populated properly since i printed out the values successfully as seen here http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1166-288.html  I do not need the checkboxes but i used this code since i followed it from an example i used earlier.

Could you please guide me where the mistake lies that i am getting this odd output.

```
    function freeway_dashboard_details(){

 $pidobtained = $_GET['project_id'] ;


  $fileId = array();
   $fileName = array();
  $srcLang = array();
   $targLang = array();
   $statusId = array();
   $statusDesc = array();

   $LoginClient = new SoapClient("https://freeway.demo.company.com/vojo/FreewayAuth.asmx?wsdl", array("trace"=>1)); 
  $ServicesLink = new SoapClient("https://freeway.demo.company.com/vojo/Service.asmx?wsdl", array("trace"=>1));

        try
        {
            $arrResponse = $LoginClient->Logon(array ('Username'=>'','Password'=>''));
            $ticket = ($arrResponse->LogonResult);
            $fileStatus = $ServicesLink->GetFileStatus(array('Ticket'=>$ticket,'ProjectID'=>$pidobtained,'SourceLanguageID'=> "", 'TargetLanguageID'=> "",'FileID'=> "",'Filename'=>""));
            $arrayPid = array();

            foreach($fileStatus->GetFileStatusResult->FileStatuses->FileStatus as $fileStatusObtained)
            {
                $arrayPid = get_object_vars($fileStatusObtained);
                //print_r($fileStatusObtained->FileID);                 
                 $fileId [] = $fileStatusObtained->FileID;
                 $fileName[] = $fileStatusObtained->Filename;
                 $srcLang[] =  $fileStatusObtained->SourceLanguageID;
                 $targLang[] = $fileStatusObtained->TargetLanguageID;
                 $statusId[] = $fileStatusObtained->StatusID;
                 $statusDesc[] = $fileStatusObtained->StatusDescription;
            }





          for($n=0;$n <count($fileId);$n+=1){
           $options[$fileId[$n]] = '';
           $form[$fileId[$n]]['FileID'] = array('#value' =>  $fileId[$n]);
           $form[$fileName[$n]]['FileName'] = array('#value' =>  $fileName[$n]);
           $form[$srcLang[$n]]['SrcLang'] = array('#value' =>  $srcLang[$n]);
           $form[$targLang[$n]]['TarLang'] = array('#value' =>  $targLang[$n]); 
           $form[$statusId[$n]]['StatusID'] = array('#value' =>  $statusId[$n]);    
           $form[$statusDesc[$n]]['StatusDesc'] = array('#value' =>  $statusDesc[$n]);                 
          }

        }

        catch(SoapFault $exception)
        {                  
           return $exception;

        }


        $form['featured'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#options' => $options,
        '#multiple' => false,
        );

   return $form;


 }



  function freeway_theme() {
 return array('freeway_dashboard' => array('arguments' => array('form' => NULL),),'freeway_dashboard_details' => array('arguments' => array('form' => NULL),),);
     }



     function theme_freeway_dashboard_details($form) {
            $rows = array();
            foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {
            $row = array();
                    if (isset($form[$key]['FileID'])) {
                    $status = drupal_render($form['featured'][$key]);
                    $row[] = array('data' => $status, 'class' => 'checkbox');
                    $row[] = ''. drupal_render($form[$key]['FileID']) .'';
                    $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['FileName']));
                    $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['SrcLang']));
                    $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['TarLang']));
                    $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['StatusID']));




                    $rows[] = $row;

                    }

            }
            $header = array();
            $header[] = array('data' => t('Featured'), 'class' => 'checkbox');
            $header[] = t('File ID');
            $header[] = t('File Name');
            $header[] = t('Source Language');
            $header[] = t('Target Language');
            $header[] = t('Status ID');
            $header[] = t('Status Description');


            $output = theme('table', $header, $rows,array('size'=>10, 'class' => 'table_class'));
            $output .= drupal_render($form);


        return $output;

      }
```

Thanks
Angela

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in there I think, mainly that your assigning of form keys is inconsistent so some elements are actually overwriting existing ones, and some aren't being found in your loop and are being outputted after the table as normal form items. Your code could probably be a bit shorter as well, try this:

In `freeway_dashboard_details()`:

```
$form['#table_values'] = array();
$options = array();
foreach ($fileStatus->GetFileStatusResult->FileStatuses->FileStatus as $fileStatusObtained) {
  $form['#table_values'][$fileStatusObtained->FileID] = array(
    'fileId' => $fileStatusObtained->FileID,
    'fileName' => $fileStatusObtained->Filename,
    'srcLang' => $fileStatusObtained->SourceLanguageID,
    'targLang' => $fileStatusObtained->TargetLanguageID,
    'statusId' => $fileStatusObtained->StatusID,
    'statusDesc' => $fileStatusObtained->StatusDescription
   );

  $options[$fileStatusObtained->FileID] = '';
}

$form['featured'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#multiple' => false,
);
```

And in `freeway_theme()`:

```
$rows = array();
foreach (element_children($form['featured']) as $key) {
  $row = array();
  if (isset($form['#table_values'][$key])) {
    $status = drupal_render($form['featured'][$key]);
    $row[] = array('data' => $status, 'class' => 'checkbox');
    $row[] = array('data' => $form['#table_values'][$key]['fileId']);
    $row[] = array('data' => $form['#table_values'][$key]['fileName']);
    $row[] = array('data' => $form['#table_values'][$key]['srcLang']);
    $row[] = array('data' => $form['#table_values'][$key]['targLang']);
    $row[] = array('data' => $form['#table_values'][$key]['statusId']);
    $row[] = array('data' => $form['#table_values'][$key]['statusDesc']);

    $rows[] = $row;
  }
}

// Rest of the code as it was
```